# Android Studio emulator run: PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, nativescript

I'm trying to get NativeScript Vue working with the Android emulator, but I think I've got a problem with my Android Studio setup. I can't get the emulator running via Android Studio (I've setup a few AVDs with no luck). It always ends up with the same error in the event log:

```
Emulator: PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Android\sdk]!

Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've tried changing the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT env variable to a paths with no luck. I'm not really sure where it's meant to be pointing really.

I have had a look at some of the answers to this question on Stack Overflow but most of them relate to the command line.

Appreciate any help I can get on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe some errors in sdk paths reg.
use [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) as alternative for avd. thats lite, fast start, free for personal use and easy to use

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Is this easy to set up with NativeScript?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by creating a Windows user without an accent or special characters and reinstalling android studio on that user. But its user is "James". Another change is to change the environment variables:

**Left Click in My Computer > Advanced System Settings> Advanced > Environment Variables**

> ANDROID_HOME = c:\my_sdk_path
>
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = c:\my_sdk_path
>
> JAVA_HOME = c:\program files\Java\yourJavaPath

- the default path of SDK is c:\users\youruser\AppData\LocalAndroid\sdk

[image: Environment variables]

**Add in Path Variable the values:**

> 1. %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
> 2. %ANDROID_HOME%\tools

[image: path variables]

[image: path values]

After changes, restart windows and try again!